# SequelizeJS migration: Adding multiple foreign keys to the same model?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

When using the `sequelize cli` utility's migration feature, new foreign keys can be created by adding a new column. However, I'm running into an error when trying to create multiple foreign keys to the same model. The foreign key names produced by running `sequelize db:migrate` are not distinctive. The DB engine requires that all foreign keys are assigned a unique name, but SequelizeJS seem to initally name all foreign keys as:

```
// Excerpt from sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query-generator.js
// Line 195
{fkName: this.quoteIdentifier(attrName + '_foreign_idx')}
```

and this will of course produce equal keys if the index number `idx` isn't correctly incremented.

Somewhere in the Sequelize library, the `idx` part of `_foreign_idx` must be replaced by an actual numeric value when initializing models using `db.sync()`, but I haven't been able to identify where. I've also verified that sequelize indeed increment the index value when using `db.sync()` by inspecting the foreign keys in another database. In that database, the foreign keys were named as `_ibfk_1`, `_ibfk_2`, .., `_ibfk_n`

- Have anyone encountered a problem where the foreign key generator
  produces identical names?
- Does anyone have a suggestion as to how
  this can be avoided / alleviated when using Sequelize migrations?

I'm using *MySQL* as the database engine, but the foreign key name generator follows the same procedure for eg. postgre as well, as far as I was able to interpret the sequelize source code.

## Example

The following migration will create three models and create a relations between them using the function addColumn function from `sequelize cli`.

The script models a scenario where both a *coach* and a *team* is sponsored by some *sponsor*. In this model, we would like to hold a reference to the sponsor id in both our coach and team model. Unfortunately, this will create two foreign keys with the name `sponsorId_foreign_idx` (one on the coach and one on the team model) and thus the foreign keys will not have unique names. This would however be avoided if `idx` was changed by some incremented value.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return Promise
      .join(
        queryInterface
          .createTable('sponsor', {
            id: {
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true,
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            name: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
          }),
        queryInterface
          .createTable('team', {
            id: {
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true,
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            name: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
          }),
        queryInterface
          .createTable('coach', {
            id: {
              autoIncrement: true,
              primaryKey: true,
              type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            name: {
              type: Sequelize.STRING
            },
          })
      )
      .then(function(){
        return queryInterface
          .addColumn('team', 'sponsorId', {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            references: { model: 'sponsor', key: 'id' }
          })
          .then(function(){
            return queryInterface
              .addColumn('coach', 'sponsorId', {
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                references: { model: 'sponsor', key: 'id' }
              });
          });
      });
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.dropAllTables(); 
  }
};
```

## Complete error log dump

```
{ SequelizeBaseError: ER_DUP_KEY: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-3b7_f1'
    at Query.formatError (/home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:175:14)
    at Query._callback (/home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:49:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:86:24)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:94:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:74:12)
    at Protocol.write (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  message: 'ER_DUP_KEY: Can\'t write; duplicate key in table \'#sql-3b7_f1\'',
  parent: 
   { Error: ER_DUP_KEY: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-3b7_f1'
       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
       at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
       at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
       at Parser.write (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:74:12)
       at Protocol.write (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
       --------------------
       at Protocol._enqueue (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
       at Connection.query (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:214:25)
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:40:21
       at Promise._execute (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
       at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
       at new Promise (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
       at Query.run (/home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:39:17)
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:849:20
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:40:21
       at Promise._execute (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
       at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
       at new Promise (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
       at retryAsPromised (/home/usr/me/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:30:10)
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:848:12
       at tryCatcher (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
     code: 'ER_DUP_KEY',
     errno: 1022,
     sqlState: '23000',
     index: 0,
     sql: 'ALTER TABLE `coach` ADD `sponsorId` INTEGER, ADD CONSTRAINT `sponsorId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`sponsorId`) REFERENCES `sponsor` (`id`);' },
  original: 
   { Error: ER_DUP_KEY: Can't write; duplicate key in table '#sql-3b7_f1'
       at Query.Sequence._packetToError (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:52:14)
       at Query.ErrorPacket (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Query.js:83:18)
       at Protocol._parsePacket (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:280:23)
       at Parser.write (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:74:12)
       at Protocol.write (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:39:16)
       at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:109:28)
       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
       at TCP.onread (net.js:551:20)
       --------------------
       at Protocol._enqueue (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
       at Connection.query (/home/usr/me/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:214:25)
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:40:21
       at Promise._execute (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
       at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
       at new Promise (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
       at Query.run (/home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:39:17)
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:849:20
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:40:21
       at Promise._execute (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:300:9)
       at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:481:18)
       at new Promise (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:77:14)
       at retryAsPromised (/home/usr/me/node_modules/retry-as-promised/index.js:30:10)
       at /home/usr/me/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:848:12
       at tryCatcher (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/usr/me/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
     code: 'ER_DUP_KEY',
     errno: 1022,
     sqlState: '23000',
     index: 0,
     sql: 'ALTER TABLE `coach` ADD `sponsorId` INTEGER, ADD CONSTRAINT `sponsorId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`sponsorId`) REFERENCES `sponsor` (`id`);' },
  sql: 'ALTER TABLE `coach` ADD `sponsorId` INTEGER, ADD CONSTRAINT `sponsorId_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`sponsorId`) REFERENCES `sponsor` (`id`);' }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a suitable workaround? Looks like this [was fixed in their v4 development](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/6008) but not in v3.

Comment: I resorted to write tailored SQL queries using the interface exposed at `queryInterface.sequelize.query` ([it's existence is mentioned on the github page](https://github.com/sequelize/cli))

Answer (score 2):

After some digging I found that [this is a bug](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/5826) introduced in v3.21. Someone kindly [fixed it in the v4 alpha branch](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/6008) but not in v3 which is the current release branch. I submitted a [backport of the patch](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/7431) for v3, but it will be a while until it makes it into a release.

In the meantime, I resorted to using manual queries like you recommended in your comment above. It's not too painful because it only affects adding / changing queries on existing tables but not foreign keys on new tables.

The examples are a bit vague in the docs, so for others that may stumble across this question here's what I have from an umzug migration.

```js
up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface
        .addColumn('operators', 'organization_id', {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            allowNull: true,
            // This bit will cause the naming conflict
            // references: { model: 'organizations', key: 'id' },
            // onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
            // onDelete: 'RESTRICT'
        })
        .then(() => queryInterface
            .sequelize
            .query('ALTER TABLE `operators` ADD CONSTRAINT `operators_organization_id_foreign_idx` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;',
                { type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.RAW }));
},
```